# Using JSInterop to pass object to JavaScript results in empty object

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, asp.net-core, blazor

Within ASP.Net Core I'm trying to build basic bindings for Google Maps from C# code. Using JSInterop I can successfully pass strings to JavaScript functions but when I try to pass more complex objects, the object appears empty in the JavaScript function.

I've partly followed [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/using-bing-maps-in-blazor-with-jsinterop-and-typescript-90e888e0e2fd) and modified it to use Google Maps rather than Bing Maps.

As in the tutorial, I've found [TypeScript definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/googlemaps) for Google Maps to help code the bindings.

I have the following razor file, which should load a map when the user clicks the button:

```
@page "/sitemapper"
@inherits SiteMapperBase

<h3>Map</h3>

<div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 70vh;"></div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@OpenMap">Click me</button>

@code {
void OpenMap()
{
    LoadMap();
}
}
```

The corresponding `.razor.cs` file has the following `LoadMap` method:

```
        protected async Task LoadMap()
        {
            LatLng center = new LatLng(40.417268, -3.696050);
            MapOptions options = new MapOptions("map", center, 8);
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Task>("loadMap", options);
        }
```

The C# classes in the above code are defined here:

```
public class MapOptions
    {
        public string elementId;
        public LatLng center;
        public int zoom;

        public MapOptions(string elementId, LatLng center, int zoom)
        {
            this.elementId = elementId;
            this.center = center;
            this.zoom = zoom;
        }
    }

    public class LatLng
    {
        public double lat;
        public double lng;

        public LatLng(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            lat = latitude;
            lng = longitude;
        }
    }
```

On the JavaScript/TypeScript side, I have defined the following interfaces, which match the C# classes:

```
interface GoogleMapOptionsInterface {
    center: GoogleMapLatLngInterface,
    zoom: number,
    elementId: string
}

interface GoogleMapLatLngInterface {
    lat: number,
    lng: number
}
```

Finally, I have a GoogleTsInterop.ts file, with my TypeScript code:

```
/// <reference path="types/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="interfaces/GoogleMapsInterfaces.ts" />

let googleMap: GoogleMap;

class GoogleMap {
    map: google.maps.Map;

    constructor(options: GoogleMapOptionsInterface) {
        console.log("constructor");
        var mapElement = document.getElementById(options.elementId);
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
            center: options.center,
            zoom: options.zoom
        });
    }
}

function loadMap(options: GoogleMapOptionsInterface) {
    new GoogleMap(options);
}
```

When I try run this, the map does not load, and looking in the browsers debugger shows me that the `options` object in the `loadMap(...)` function is an empty object (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyFaI.png)) (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to put the image in directly).

If I change my code I can successfully pass a string with the following: `await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Task>("loadMap", "test");`. However I want to pass the object.

Is there a way to do this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you pass it as a JsonResult or JSON string?

```
MapOptions options = new MapOptions("map", center, 8);
JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Task>("loadMap", Json(options));
```

or

```
MapOptions options = new MapOptions("map", center, 8);
var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(options);
JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Task>("loadMap", result);
```

Comment: where is that Json(...) method coming from?

Comment: NewtonsoftJson or any other library that converts objects to Json format

Answer (score 0):

There is two problems with this code.
First : Add getter and setter to the latitude and longitude

```
    public double latitude { get; set; }        
    public double longitude { get; set; }
```

Second :
the typescript function is a void, so you need to invoke a void

```
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("yourFunction", yourObject);
```